# Product Price Alignment WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get the product prices on the same lone for each product. As you can see from the image below, products that have longer names are having their prices misaligned.[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can add css to your product title class like :

```
.product_title_class{
        min-height:80px // 80px is just for example
}
```

Comment: Thank you this really assisted me.